# Does Ubuntu One offer a corporate account

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am interested in having all of our computers in our company syncing with Ubuntu One.  Is there a corporate account program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this moment in time. Ubuntu One is a fairly new service though, I would expect more options to show up in time. As of right now there is only the Basic Account and the Mobile Account.

Comment: Any update on this question?  Any future plans for a corporate Ubuntu One plan?